# Inequality regarding sum of the squares of the logarithms of primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I have been following an elementary proof of the prime number theorem and the author makes use of the following inequality
$$\sum_{p \leq x} \log^{2}(p) = \psi(x)\log(x) + O(x) $$
where $\psi(x) = \sum_{p \leq x} \log(p)$ and the sums are over prime numbers.

I tried bounding the difference using the fact that $\Pi(x) = O\left(\frac{x}{\log(x)}\right)$ and by calculating the sums between $\frac{x}{2^n}$ and $\frac{x}{2^{n+1}}$ separately but I get a $O(x\log(x))$ remainder. Summation by parts also results in the same problem when bounding$\frac{\psi(x) - \psi(k)}{k}$.

I would appreciate if anyone could give me a few hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial summation gives for integer $x$ $$\sum_{p\le x} \log^2 p = \theta(x)\log x+\sum_{n\le x-1} \theta(n)(\log n-\log(n+1))$$ $$=(\psi(x)+O(x^{1/2}\log x))\log x+\sum_{n\le x-1} O(n)O(1/n)$$

Comment: What is $\theta$ here?

Comment: $\theta(x) = \sum_{p \leq x} \log(p)$, $\psi(x) = \sum_{p^k \leq x} \log(p)$ this is the usual notation in the theory of $\zeta(s)$ I assumed the OP confused the two

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thanks for the explanation :]

Comment: $\theta(x)=O(x)$ is the same as $\pi(x)=O(x/\log x)$ they follow from $O(4^n)={2n\choose n} \ge \prod_{p\in (n,2n]} p$